# sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gns3/ppa | gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found

Tags: linux, installation, repository

i was following the instructions to install gns3 on my linux, and it appears that the first command of adding the ppa to repository didn't work.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gns3/ppa

 PPA for GNS3 and Supporting Packages. Please see http://www.gns3.com for more details
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~gns3/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmpmnmly0qq/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: /tmp/tmpmnmly0qq/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 9A2FD067A2E3EF7B: public key "Launchpad PPA for GNS3" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your problem is stated in the last line:

"gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found."

The problem might go away by running:

```bash
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates
```

Comment: no it didn't, i tried this before asking the question